# Guidance for mysql 5.6 install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I have followed the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-debian.html to a T twice now and twice it appears it hasn't worked. There is no my.cnf under /etc, there is no data directory under /var, I'm at a loss.

Is there a better reference then the above referenced instructions? I'm logged in as my normal user account, do I need to be logged in as root? I've tried command line installation as well as the Ubuntu Software Center.

I'd like to think I'm smarter than the average bear but I'm flummoxed. I've just done a complete wipe of anything related to mysql. Trying again.

Answer (score 1):

To install mysql 5.6 you just need to do the following:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

You can login as root to run the command or sudo it. After that, you can tune up the /etc/my.cnf file